# Why is this if statement returning something contradictory?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to make this pig latin function, but ran in to this weird problem. When I check to see if the first character is in the vowels array, which it isn't, the if statement returns that it is!

So I checked to see if there was something wrong with my condition, but it clearly returns -1.

If this isn't -1, return the index of the letter is what I'm asking, and it returns -1. Makes no sense at all.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

  if (vowels.indexOf(str.charAt(0) != -1)){
    return vowels.indexOf(str.charAt(0));
  } else {
    return false;
  } 
}

translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You have wrong `( ... )` there :)

Comment: you are doing the `!= -1` inside of the `indexOf` argument!

Comment: dang thanks for pointing that out guys, I feel dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your if statement, you are checking the indexOf your condition. You just want to check the indexOf(str.charAt(0)). So, rewrite that line to:

```
if (vowels.indexOf(str.charAt(0)) != -1){
```